# How to delete a table when i know half name of the table in ci

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have a tables combination of two names , these two names are in different table like friend 1 and friend 2 . when i delete one name from the friend 1 or friend 2,  i should delete the combination table . now i know only the half of the name of the table example :
the table name is thamaraiselvam_kuppuraj
when i delete kuppuraj from the friends 2 table. i should delete thamaraiselvam_kuppuraj table also. 
how to write query for this?

```
$this->dbforge->drop_table('table name');
```

can i use above query with some modification?

thank in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to find the name of the table:

```
show tables like '%_kuppuraj'
```

Now you have name of the table.

Comment: how to get table name from the result
$sql="show tables like '%_".$table_name."'";
$result=$this->db->query($sql);

foreach ($result -> result() as $delete) {
print_r( $delete);
 }
i got results but problem is , i dont know how to get table name from result